# Creating DATEID column in Power Query causes Stack Overflow

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

[image: Error Message]

> Expression.Error: Evaluation resulted in a stack overflow and cannot continue.

I'm trying to add a custom column so I have a DATEID in my Date table it causes a stack overflow. Thought this would be the forum for this error. The date table contains dates from 1980 to 2038.

Formulae for new column in DATE TABLE:

```
Table.AddColumn(Time, "DateKey", 
    each 
      Number.ToText(Date.Year([Date])) &
      Text.PadStart(Number.ToText(Date.Month([Date])),2,"0") &
      Text.PadStart(Number.ToText(Date.Day([Date])),2,"0"
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why it's throwing an error but you may have better luck with a cleaner definition using the function [Date.ToText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/date-totext).

```
Date.ToText([Date], "yyyyMMdd")
```